# IOSTAT report doesn't match with DD benchmark

Tags: synchronization, dd, iostat

I am running a DD benchmark but the obtained results are not matching with the IOSTAT values.

This is the DD sample:

```
$ sudo dd bs=4096 count=690 if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/tmp/test oflag=dsync
690+0 records in
690+0 records out
2826240 bytes (2,8 MB) copied, 29,2135 s, 96,7 kB/s
```

While this benchmark is running, the "iostat -x 1" is reporting on "wkB/s" values between 500 and 600 kB/s.

Something's wrong here.. well, if I don't use the DSYNC, the values are matching.. but I want to do a constant sync for each write operation. Maybe IOSTAT doesn't work well with DSYNC operations ?!

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: You are writing to a file, so with `oflag=dsync` you will invoke a data AND a metadata sync on every block. It is quite possible, that in this pathological case the overhead is much higher than the payload.

Comment: I chose DSYNC because it "does not flush modified metadata unless that metadata is needed in order to allow a subsequent data retrieval to be correctly handled.  For example, changes to st_atime or st_mtime".Reading that about DSYNC.. it's seems not reasonable for so much difference between iostat and DD...

So.. I believe this way has the lowest possible overhead.

Comment: Every single block needs a metadata update: File length